# Sliding Transformer model into longer sequence

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have very long genome sequences where I have to do some classification stuff on top. What I want to try is to use a transformer to predict the next token from the 512 chunk sequence and slide this transformer to the whole sequence and use those to work on top of the whole sequence.

Let’s say an example: Imagine I have a 250.000 token sequence, I should slide the transformer 488 times producing 488 tokens. Concatenate this output to obtain a summary array of the sequence and build a classifier on top of it.

I’m trying to find any examples that could guide me in this direction but I hardly can find any of them. Does someone think that’s a good idea? Where could I look for some near examples of sliding a transformer/LSTM over a longer sequence?

[image: conceptual example]

Thank you very much, I’ll appreciate everything!

Comment: Please check longformer for modeling long sequence. https://github.com/allenai/longformer

Comment: @joe32140 thanks! But as I've been seeing, longformers usually take approaches on max 8k tokens more or less right?

Comment: What do you mean by `sliding`? Is the 65th token part of several chunks or just of one chunk (in other words, is there an overlap between the chunks)? As far as I understand your question, you can just take a transformer that can handle 512 tokens (nearly all) and split up your sequence during preprocessing,

Comment: @cronoik Sorry for this late answer. Thanks for your interest! I have edited the question up there, with some more visual explanation... Hope it helps with the understanding. Regarding your questions: There should be no overlap. Do you think it would work just by doing the first part as a preprocessing schedule and then another NN working with the concatenated results?